# ImageView animation like the Android 4.0+ contact editor

Tags: android, android-imageview

I would like to animate my ImageView like the contact editor (the read only mode) in Android 4.0+ does (I am not sure about the version). 
But I don't know where to start. I tried to figure out what the source code does, but it is really complicated and I am not even sure, if I am looking at the right source code (PhotoSelectionActivity?).

So, here is what I would like to do:
I have an ImageView (400dp x 200dp, width x height) and a quadratic image resource. I would like to draw my image in that ImageView using the centerCrop scale type (done so far). But when the user clicks the ImageView, it should expand to its full size (if possible do not change the layout size, because it is not the only view in the linear layout), the background (if possible) should fade out.

Any ideas?

Here is an image of the start view:
[image]

and when the user clicks the image, an animation should start, ending with this view (keep in mind, that the contacts details are still there, they are just behind the image):
[image]

I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this create two corresponding animations (scale and fade out) with [Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Use [NineOldAnroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) for backwards compatability with Android 2.x.

Comment: Scale does not work as expected with scaleType="centerCrop"... I expect it to slowly show the picture without cropping, but it scales the cropped image.

Comment: OK, got it. But I can't advise something particular because without seeing it it is still not fully clear what you want to achieve. Anyway I think you should implement cropping by yourself and then use property animations depending on how you decided to implement cropping.